# how to sort arraylist using enum type

Tags: java

I have an arraylist of cards ArrayList hand;
suppose hand={2S,3H,2D,6H,4C}. I need a method to sort the arraylist hand so that I get `hand = {4C,2D,3H,6H,2S}`. I know that enum has a method `compareTo()`, but I am not sure how to use it. Can anyone give me some guidance?

```
public class PlayingCard implements Comparable
 {
//Instance Variables
private Suit suit;
private Rank rank;

//Constructor
public PlayingCard(Suit suit, Rank rank)
{
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
}
....
 public int compareTo(Object other)
 {
  PlayingCard that = (PlayingCard)other;

  if (this.suit == that.suit)
     return -this.rank.compareTo(((PlayingCard)other).rank);

  return -this.suit.compareTo(((PlayingCard)other).suit);         
 }

//============================================================================
 //Representation of the Suit of a Playing-Card
public enum Suit
{
    CLUBS('C'), DIAMONDS('D'), HEARTS('H'), SPADES('S');

    private char symbol;

    private Suit(char symbol)
    {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public char getSymbol()
    {
        return this.symbol;
    }
}

//============================================================================  
 //Representation of the Rank os a Playing-Card
public enum Rank
{
    DEUCE('2'), TREY('3'), FOUR('4'), FIVE('5'), SIX('6'), SEVEN('7'),
    EIGHT('8'), NINE('9'), TEN('T'), JACK('J'), QUEEN('Q'), KING('K'), ACE('A');

    private char symbol;

    private Rank(char symbol)
    {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public char getSymbol()
    {
        return this.symbol;
    }
}
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class PlayingCardHand {
//Instance Variables

private int cardsInCompleteHand;     //Maximum # cards in this hand
private ArrayList<PlayingCard> hand; //A hand of Playing-Cards
private Comparator comparer;         //Client-provided comparison of PlayingCards

//Constructor
//Appropriate when PlayingCard compareTo() is to be used to compare PlayingCards
public PlayingCardHand(int handSize) {

    if (handSize < 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Hand size cannot be less than 1");
    }
    cardsInCompleteHand = handSize;
    hand = new ArrayList<PlayingCard>();

}
...
public void sortCards() 
{
}
```

Comment: Do you have an object that represents a card? You've only shown us two enums that represents the components of a card.

Comment: Yes, I have the object that represents the card

Comment: @user1166061, Can you show us the code?

Comment: This is my PlayingCard class, which has a compareTo(). I have another class to represent a hand and I need to sort them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a `compareTo()` method on the `Card` which sorts first by `Rank`, and if `Rank` is equal, then by `Suit`.  If we use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), it's very simple:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card>
{
  private Rank rank;
  private Suit suit;

  ...

  public int compareTo(Card that) 
  {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
      .compare(this.rank, that.rank)
      .compare(this.suit, that.suit)
      .result();
  }
}
```

Here's the Javadoc for [`ComparisonChain`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html).

If we assume that a *hand* is a `List<Card>`, then you can sort your list using `Collections.sort(hand)`.

Comment: I am sorry for not posting the whole code earlier. Yes hand is a Arraylist<PlayingCard> and I need to sort the hand using Collections.sort(hand)

Comment: @user1166061: has this answered your question? If so, you should mark you question as answered.

Comment: No, it hasn't. I posted the rest of the code to see if someone can help me come up with a way to write the sort method.

Comment: @user1166061: The sort method needs to be defined for `Card` and is written above. How to sort a `List` is also written above.  If it hasn't answered your question, perhaps you should explain why. :-)